# BehaviorSubject emits only initial value on other angular component

Tags: angular, angular-components, subscribe, behaviorsubject

I'm having a weird problem, I created a service to emit the value of the item clicked on the navbar, so I could
fire a modal .

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from "rxjs";
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HeaderService {
modalShowObservable = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

private modal$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
selectedModal$ = this.modal$.asObservable();


changeModalDisplay(modal: string): void {
    this.modalShowObservable.next(modal)
    this.modal$.next(modal)
}
```

Both approaches works well for the component itself, and I can display on the screen the value emitted by BehaviorSubject, subscribing and assigning the value to a property in the component

But when I try to subscribe from another component I only get the initial value

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.headerService.modalShowObservable.subscribe({ valor => {
    console.log("test") //runs when starting componet
    console.log(valor) // ''
})
  
  this.headerService.selectedModal$.subscribe(valor => {
    console.log("test") //runs when starting componet
    console.log(valor) //{}
})
```

}

I can't understand what's wrong, everything I've read seems to indicate doing it this way

Why can't I subscribe it from another component?

Comment: Are you using the `changeModalDisplay` to change the value to begin with?

Comment: yes, its call from a event passing a string, like changeModalDisplay('clientSelect'), I manage to fix as I say on my answer below, 
Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

If all obvious solutions don't help, make sure your application creates only one object of your @Injectable service. You can test that by adding a log line to the constructor of the Service, like

```
constructor(){
  console.log("SERVICE CONSTRUCTOR");
}
```

If this shows up more than once in your logging, angular Injects the wrong object in your Components and your app will never do anything useful.

Change

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'any'})
```

into

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the problem, I provided the service inside the component in which it worked by the Components providers array, apparently this creates some bind, I'm not sure, I just removed the annotation and it worked correctly in others components

```
@Component({


 selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
  //providers: [HeaderService]
})
```

Answer (score -1):

What is wrong is that your `modalShowObservable` variable is not an observable but a `BehaviorSubject`, if you want to transform it to an observable you would have to do the same as your have done for `modal$` and `selectedModal$` with `this.modal$.asObservable()`, this way you have allowed components that can access to `HeaderService` to subscribe to changes.

I have tried to reproduced what you want to do with a simple counter service shared across two components.

```
// in first.component.html
<button (click)="increaseCounter(counter)">Increase Count</button>

// in first.component.ts
increaseCounter() {
  this.counter = this.counter + 1;
  this.headerService.setCounterValue(this.counter);
}

// in header.service.ts
private count$$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
count$ = this.count$$.asObservable();

setCounterValue(count: number): void {
  this.count$$.next(count);
}

// in second.component.html
<h1>Count = {{ counter }}</h1>

// in second.component.ts 
const sub = this.headerService.selectedModal$.subscribe((count) => {
  this.counter = count;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact I made another mistake, I provided the service inside the providers array of the component that worked, I don't know exactly why but it seems that this makes it inaccessible to other components, just remove that it worked magically

Comment: BehaviorSubject IS Observable. It's more than observable, it's multicasting observable, but still has all features from Observable. Restrict public properties to just observable with `asObservable()` when you want to prevent class consumers from nexting values to Subject.